# what is the default location for boost library when installed using macport on mac ?

Tags: c++, macos, boost, macports

I just now installed  boost on mac, using macport with following command

```
sudo port install boost
```

It's installed fine, but I have no idea where the boost library got installed to.
Where should it be / how could I search for it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The headers should be in `/usr/local/include/boost` and the libs should be in `/usr/local/lib.` Or in `/opt/local/include/boost` and `/opt/local/lib`, I believe.

You can search using `locate`:

```
locate boost
```

Comment: What? `dpkg -s libboost-all-dev` says `Status: install ok installed`. `locate boost` gives me nothing. Same for all the directories you give me...

Answer (score 3):

Using the `macOS Sierra 10.13.5`, installed `boost` with `brew`. location in `/usr/local/include/`

Answer (score 2):

For me, with High Sierra and MacPorts 2.4.4, MacPorts installed Boost 1.66 under:

```
/opt/local/include/boost
```

Answer (score 1):

Default is /usr/local/lib /usr/local/include

You might want to rebuild the libs using the clang toolchain

```
./bjam toolset=clang
```

and then do a manual install in a specific location especially if you want to switch between versions (for source control or testing etc)

```
> find . -name boost
```

also works

Comment: Why he needs to rebuild the libs with clang?